# arabic language encoding in web application asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, arabic

i made a web application using asp.net c# code behind
and its work all fine on every computer ... i try it on this laptop but it gave me and encode problem

i try to change the encode of the browser and to copy the font from other computer but it didn't work

what should i do ?

web.config :

```
  </pages>
      <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="he-IL"/>     </system.web>   <system.webServer>
```

note : the application in Arabic language .

please  i need a help very fast

[image]

Comment: Read [MSDN documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6eedwbtt(v=vs.140).aspx), it clearly says `if you create ASP.NET Web pages with Arabic names, users without the Windows Arabic language pack will neither be able to enter those names nor display the pages correctly`

Answer (score 1):

you should add Arabic language from the control panel -> region and language ->administrative ->change system local and add Arabic language